# Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't recognize external hard drive or flashdrive on my Dell Studio 1558

Tags: usb, hard-drive, dell

I just installed Ubuntu into my old Dell Windows 7 laptop and it doesn't recognize my external hard drive or flash drive. I tried searching but I don't find any solutions online.
Can anyone explain how to solve this for a non initiated?

Answer (score 1):

The first place to start looking is always at previous posts on the topic... even a post for Ubuntu 16.04 and older will have relevent information, as this is a common issue. Search the forums for "external drive not recognized".

Next, without having details on the type of external drive (OP should edit post to include format of the drives - NTFS, exFAT etc.) the output of "dmesg", to see what your kernel says about the drive after it is plugged in, is the next step:

```
~/> dmesg | tail -n 10
[15311.006693] usb 1-1.2.4.5: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
<snip...>
[15311.100736] usb 1-1.2.4.5: Product: Storage Media
<snip...>
[15312.342990] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[15312.349159]  sdb: sdb1
[15312.351872] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Where you want to see the bit telling you that the system has detected the partition on the drive correctly - see "sdb: sdb1" above. Then you can go look at format support, and auto-mounting issues.

Comment: Ok, so now that I had the chance to test my laptop a bit more I can expand my problem. Actually, the USB ports don't work at all, and neither does the HDMI port, I tried some input on the terminal and the device I connect on the USB port shows there but nothing else happens... maybe since it's a new installation there are some drivers I need to install or something I'm missing.

Comment: @Lucho: Ok, that's a more fundamental issue. You'll find a whole lot of posts on driver checks on the forums (using tools like lspci, lsusb, and lsmod to figure out what is working and what not), so go have a search. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, now I'm making some progress with the guides here, but I still couldn't mount my External Hard drive. When I try to mount it, I get this error message:

Comment: mount: /home/user/Desktop: mount point does not exist.
luchopucho@luchopucho-Studio-1558:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /home
mount: /home: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
luchopucho@luchopucho-Studio-1558:~$

Comment: The Ext HD I'm trying to mount is ExFat format, since I use it whith Mac and PC and changing format is not an option. I must also mention that I can't even have an USB mouse to work, it turns on but it doesn't move the cursor

Comment: Ok, this is just driving me crazy. I started the computer with the mouse connected to the USB port and now it works... WTF!

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe I'm saying this but my experience with Ubuntu just sucks, I had Windows 7 and it actually worked faster and better. I regret that I completely erased it from my hard drive, so now I'm stuck to this piece of...

Comment: For ExFAT you need the exfat-utils and fuse-exfat packages. There'll be lots of posts on those too. When USB devices freeze up a USB BUS controller, it can also take down other attached devices, like the mouse/kb etc.

Comment: Ok, I managed to have my ExFAT hard drive working, I just have to restart the computer every time I want to use it, which is quite annoying. Then after 3 weeks with Ubuntu, I can confirm that it works slower than Windows 7 and it also freezes more often. I'm now considering to install Lubuntu, but then I'll have to re-install every software I already installed and nothing tells me it's gonna work... unless, there's a way to test it before installing it... and surely, again you'll tell me to go through the whole forum for answers. Wouldn't it be easier to just make an OS that works???